# Unity Why when I create new tiles and drag the tile set in the palette it's merged together?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity 2D Game, Why when I create new tiles and drag the tile set in the palette it's merged together, like in the image?

**my palette**

[image: my palette]

**tileset images**

[image: tileset images]

**Here my palette must show the tile set like this!**

[image: Here my palette must show the tile set like this!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tileset, go to the sprite editor, open the 'Slice' menu and then check 'Keep Empty Rects'.